# Google Lighthouse Thinks Cloudflare Bot Fight Mode is Deprecated

Tags: performance, google-chrome, cloudflare

Google Lighthouse is giving me the following error under "Best Practices:"

> `window.webkitStorageInfo` is deprecated. Please use
> `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage` or
> `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage` instead.

The source file is called invisiblejs. It doesn't take much legwork to find out that this is related to Cloudflare's Bot Fight Mode setting. What I haven't been able to figure out is what to do about this. Is this a false positive on Google's part? Is there something I need to update? Is Cloudflare running deprecated code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing. It also hogs up a lot of resources that reduce the pagespeed load time. Starting to wonder if this layer of security is worth it because it may increase bounce rate with longer page load times. This is also a cyber security question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33374063)